# How can I remove the rows from a dataset which include "NA" values and less than the required amount of data?

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have this dataset which includes all the sales for a company in a given year (company code = gvkey, year = fyeqarq, sales = saley). I want to remove all rows that have NA values attributed to the company. In other words, completely erase from the dataset the companies that have as much as a single NA value. I also need to remove all companies that do not have at least 11 years of sales. Each year has four values, as it measures sales for each quarter.

I managed to remove the NA values themselves using na.omit, but I need to remove entire company data from the dataset using these two conditions.

So from the entire dataset dfUSA, this company coded with 1001 should be removed.

```
df.clean <- na.omit(dfUSA)
```

The above will only remove the NA values. But the company will still be there.

```
      gvkey   fyearq   saley
1      1001    1983    4,921 
2      1001    1983    NA
3      1001    1983    NA
4      1001    1983    NA
5      1001    1984    6,434
6      1001    1984    NA
7      1001    1984    NA
8      1001    1984    NA
9      1001    1985    7,865
10     1001    1985    NA
11     1001    1985    NA
12     1001    1985    NA
```

It also only has 3 years of data, which is another reason it should be removed. Some companies might have all sales values, but less than 11 years of data. So I would also need a way for that to be checked. How can I achieve this?

Its my first post so I can provide further information if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do a `group_by` `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df.clean <- dfUSA %>%
                   # group by the gvkey column
                   group_by(gvkey) %>%
                   # check whether there are any NA elements in saley
                   # negate (!) to change TRUE to FALSE and viceversa
                   # filter the logical vector so that it removes the whole group
                   filter(!any(is.na(saley)) %>%
                   # ungroup to be safe                   
                   ungroup()
```

---

If the intention is also to remove `any` 'gvkey' having NA or those have less than 10 'fyearq' data,

```
dfUSA %>%
      group_by(gvkey) %>%
      # along with the earlier condition check the number of unique
      # fyearq and do the negation
      filter(!(any(is.na(saley)) & n_distinct(fyearq) < 10))%>%
      # ungroup to be safe                   
       ungroup()
```

Comment: Why do we need to add `any`?!

Comment: @NelsonGon  I guess the OP wanted to remove the 'gvkey' as a whole if there are any NA elements because from the description, it says `na.omit` is not working because it removes only the NA rows.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. One last thing I just noticed though, is that each year has to appear 4 times, the reason for that is that the sales are divided by each quarter of the year. So for instance, company 1428 should have 4 "saley" objects for 1987 but only displays one, as it might only have disclosed sales for one of the quarters. How can I modify it to include this condition?

Comment: @CreditDefaultSwap  In that case, you may need to add `& all(table(fyearq) == 4)` in the `filter`